# Cannot apply the kubernetes deployment using Gitlab CI CD

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, amazon-eks

I am trying to create a Gitlab CI CD pipeline to build my java spring project and deploy it to amazon eks.
I have followed instruction as [in this article](https://medium.com/faun/ci-cd-using-gitlab-aws-eks-kubernetes-and-ecr-a55ff757b921). 
This is the gitlab-ci-cd.yml file to apply the deployment script.

```
k8s-deploy-dev:
  image: docker.io/sulemanhasib43/eks:latest
  stage: k8-deploy
  tags:
    - kubernetes
  before_script: *kubectl_config
  script:
    - sed -i "s#$CONTAINER_IMAGE#$CONTAINER_IMAGE:dev$CI_PIPELINE_IID#g" deployment.yaml
    - kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml -n dev
  only:
    - master
```

But I got an issue when applying my deployment.yml file.As following image I got an error as

> system:node:"user" cannot create resource ...

But when I am adding the eks cluster to the gitlab, I have created a user with cluster-admin role.

[image]

I have also tried adding roles to the system:node ClusterRole.

Comment: can you check `kubectl auth can-i create deployments --namespace <namespace> --as <service account>` ?

Comment: Where are you defining `kubectl_config`? The tutorial has you create a user mapping in the aws-auth configmap, but it doesn't appear that's getting used

Comment: add details i.e yaml on how you added roles to system:node ? Also the doc says use system:masters instead  and system:masters by default is already bound to cluster admin clusterrole

Comment: @hoque I got `no` as the result

Comment: @jordanm  I have add the user as the system:master in aws-auth cm

 `mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::**************:user/gitlab
      username: gitlab
      groups:
        - system:masters
`

Comment: @DenverShan yeah, but where are you defining in the kubeconfig to auth as that IAM user? The tutorial uses `aws eks update-kubeconfig` for that

Comment: @jordanm Yeah I am updating it in here `before_script: *kubectl_config`.
I am updating as this
`.kubectl_config: &kubectl_config
- aws eks --region *** update-kubeconfig --name ***
`

Comment: This has  defined before the stage. This config has updated successfully.